# Mock multiple beans in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I have a test in SpringBoot that should check multiple beans in very same way:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class EndpointsTest implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @MockBean
    ComponentA componentA;
    @MockBean
    ComponentB componentB;

...
```

Since I don't want to write a new dummy test for each component, I though to fetch all beans (hence the usage of `ApplicationContextAware`) and then to run test on each such bean.

Of course, these beans have to be mocked.

Is there a way to manually mock a bean like the `MockBean` annotation does and replace it the Spring context? I want also to remove explicit declaration of all components (the number is not small), just for the purpose of mocking.

EDIT: I want to avoid writing manually all the components in the test class. The component beans are named following a convention, so I want to fetch them all, apply the mock and run the test. We have 100+ components.

Comment: so if i understand you want to mock beans manually?

Comment: @Deadpool yes, exactly

Comment: but why, you can also use `@MockBean` to mock multiple beans at a time

Comment: @Deadpool dont know how - there is nothing common to all components (except the name convention). How can I apply MockBean to them all?

Answer (score 0):

I trust you have the tried the obvious?

```
@Configuration
@MockBeans({YourComponentSuperclass.class})
public class TestConfig {
}
```

If that doesn't work (for instance because @MockBean expects a single matching bean to decorate), you could write your own `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, possibly inspired by Spring's own `MockitoPostProcessor` (which makes `@MockBean` work).

Comment: I dont have a common supperclass. Now thinking, I might add the marker interface for my component.